# Argument not optional and two other relevant questions

Tags: excel, vba

Apologies if I should've created  a new thread. I wasn't sure what to do.

I'm new to this and I got this "Argument not optional" error that I can't get rid of.

Basically, I am trying to come up with a way of pasting a function in an excel sheet, click a button and normalise that function between a minimum and a maximum (in this case [0,1] ).

So far, I have this:

#

```
Sub Normalisation()

Dim FirstR As Integer, FirstC As Integer, r As Integer, c As Integer

FirstR = activecell.Row
FirstC = activecell.Column

Set max = Cells(27, 2)
Set min = Cells(28, 2)


'Normalisation
For c = 0 To Selection.Columns.Count
    For r = 0 To Selection.Rows.Count
        If Len(Cells(FirstR + r, FirstC + c)) <> 0 Then
            Cells(FirstR + r, FirstC + c + 1).Value = _
            0 + ((Cells(FirstR + r, FirstC + c) - min) * (1 - 0)) / (max - min)
        End If
    Next r
Next c

End Sub
```

#

I get the error in the line "Set max = Cells(27, 2)" and I assume the same is going to happen for the minimum.

Can you help me?

Another point is: Can I refrain from getting the maximum and minimum of my data from a cell in the excel spreadsheet, i.e., can I get the program to do it altogether? Now I have it to pick up the maximum and minimum of my data from the excel spreadsheet since I can't figure out how to calculate it from within the Sub (I really thought it would be easier..)

A final point is: It would be great if I could get a pop-up window where it asks the user between which extremes does he/she want the function to be normalised (from the formula in my code so far I had to leave it as [0,1] ).

Just as a note, I have been searching for answers to these questions for a week now. I didn't just drop them over for you guys to do the job for me... They're genuine problems.

Many thanks!

Comment: What are `max` and `min`? They seem to be ordinary (but nondeclared) variables in which case the error you get doesn't really make sense (though using `set` with them seems wrong).  Are you sure that you haven't declared `max` and `min` as functions somewhere in your project? Or -- perhaps you are using the newest version of Excel and Microsoft has finally gotten around to making `max` and `min` VBA functions.

Comment: It might just be an error in copying the code to here but it's odd that `activecell` hasn't capitalized correctly to `ActiveCell` whereas every other capitalization in the code appears to be correct. You haven't by any chance defined a variable called "activecell" anywhere, have you?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you're getting that error on that line.
Here's two ways of getting the MAX and MIN values from Sheet1 column A:

```
Sub Test()

    MsgBox Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Sheet1.Columns(1))
    'or
    MsgBox WorksheetFunction.Max(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A"))

End Sub
```

The best way to ask for both values would be to build a user form with a couple of text boxes - can ask for both values in one hit then.
Using just code you could use the code below - there are better ways I'm sure:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim sMaxValue As String
    Dim lMaxValue As Long

    Do
        sMaxValue = InputBox("Select Maximum value.", , Default:="Enter numeric value")
    Loop While Not IsNumeric(sMaxValue)

    lMaxValue = CLng(sMaxValue)

End Sub
```